# What does this script do in Perl?

Tags: perl

Can someone explain what the second half of this script does? (second line)
$self is defined elsewhere... (I know what that part does, Just wondering what the action=~... is all about/)

```
$action = "http://example.com/test.php";

$action = $self->{url} . ($action =~ /^\// ? "" : "/" ) . $action;
```

Comment: It's a search. Returns true if it matches.

Comment: Doesnt matter, You incorrectly changed my question, I did not have a question about =~, If I did, I would specifically ask that. Though I did not. I asked for the general purpose of the entire statement.

Comment: @user2864740 Also; I did isolate the syntax of my question. I could have thrown in the entire thing. Though I only put in the two lines that I had thought were necessary in understanding it. If you can't answer my question, Don't bully me about it.

Comment: @user2864740 Your telling me to refine it even more? It's 2 lines of script that you arguing to me about. If you think 2 lines is too much, Then go and downvote every single question on this website including your own. Geez, why do you have to make a big deal about that? I made it so simple and your making such a big deal that its "too obtuse" as a question...

Comment: What good is as site where the questions are "What does this script/code to in XYZ?"

Comment: @user2864740 You didn't answer my question. Also; You have a lot of other posts to down-vote. Talk to me when your finished.

Comment: @Shorthand: the purpose of this site is to help people with specific programming problems; it's not intended as a quiz or puzzle site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns an empty string if `$action` starts with a slash, and a slash if it does not start with a slash.

Comment: A single slash. Another, maybe clearer way would be to write `$action =~ m#^/#`